# php variable datatypes

Tags: php

I've just decided to venture off into PHP land for fun and to learn, reading that php is loosely typed and that $var's can be reused is this true that the code below will pose no problem?

```
$x = 996;
$x = mysql_query("SELECT aString FROM table1");
```

the variable x will stored as an int datatype with 996, then after the second line it will stored as a string datatype with the string from the query?

There wont be any casting errors?

Comment: On a side note, mysql_query doesn't return a string. It returns a MySQL Result ID which is generally an integer that refers to a particular cached result set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct; that's the definition of being "loosely typed". However, that may not be the best practice.

http://drupaler.co.uk/blog/baby-dont-you-loose-your-type-me/66 is a good read on your subject.

Comment: Exactly- using the same variable name just confuses people that have to read the code.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no errors, except that the second line won't give you a string, [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns an internal PHP type called a [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) (generally some kind of opaque handle/pointer for library functions)

Answer (score 1):

> There wont be any casting errors?

Correct!

jalf explained it well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467871/what-is-a-loosely-typed-language)